# Book series with an astronomer exploring a golden egg shaped spaceship in Earth orbit

Tags: story-identification, aliens, spaceship, nanotechnology, astronomy

So when I was younger I got a series of books involving an astronomer with Kung fu abilities who discovers a rogue object orbiting Jupiter. Next, he and his team figure out that it has left Jupiter's orbit and is on a course to intercept Earth. In there somewhere is some Russian espionage, the astronomer seduces his intern, and then by the end of the first book the plan is to send the astronomer into orbit to check out the alien spaceship that is now orbiting Earth (I believe the spacecraft was specifically egg shaped and golden). He gets inside and everyone thinks that he dies when he runs out of oxygen, but there were three books I believe and in the second one they recover his body and it turns out that somehow he got self-replicating nanobots into his bloodstream that continuously repair his organs, to the point where he no longer needs to eat or sleep. It's been some time since I read this series, but I'd like to reread them if only I could remember what they were called or even just the author's name.

Comment: To narrow it down, when were you younger? Could it be the Jupiter Theft? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Jupiter_Theft

Comment: I guess relatively speaking I didn't read them that long ago, 7-8 years ago tops, but I tend to read a lot and keeping track of titles is impossible. Anyway, I doubt they were released 7-8 years ago; I picked the series up from a second hand book store in Denver around then.

Comment: But no, it wasn't that book, thanks though!!

Comment: I figured it out!! It's the Voyagers series by Ben Bova; sorry for ruining the plot for anyone who may not have read them and wants to. After rereading a few pages of the first book, I realize that the characters may be a bit bland and the sexual elements completely unnecessary, but the plot itself is interesting and reads more like a spy novel than a science fiction one. The second book was the best in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Per Skyler's own answer, the book series in question is the [Voyagers Series](http://www.goodreads.com/series/43262-voyagers) by Ben Bova

> *Ex-astronaut turned physicist Keith Stoner knows the signals picked up at his space station are not random. The message is heading
>   straight for Earth, and Stoner will do anything to be the first man to
>   confront the enigma, even if he loses his only love.*

[image]